# The tar archive is corrupt when unpacking

Tags: php, archive, tar

I'm trying to create a `tar` archive using `php` (and `ajax`) and it gives me this error when unpacking: `"The tar archive is corrupt"` when the archive is bigger than 2GB. Everything works fine when the archive has less than 2GB.

Here is my code:

```
function download_files() {
   set_time_limit(0);

   ob_start( );
   $filename = "download.tar";
   $path = "temp/$filename";

   $files = '';
   foreach($_GET['dfile'] as $file){
       $files .= "$file ";
   }

   $cd_dir = FCPATH.'uploads';
   system("cd $cd_dir && tar -cf $path $files");

   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
   header("Content-Length: ".filesize(FCPATH."uploads/$path"));
   header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');

   ob_end_flush();
   readfile(FCPATH."uploads/$path");
   unlink(FCPATH."uploads/$path");
}
```

I tried removing `ob_*` functions and it was useless.

Any help please :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: `tar -cf $path $files"` ... this seems to be a system issue rather than a programming issue.

Comment: _“I tried removing ob_* functions and it was useless”_ – well they were rather useless to begin with … output buffering when no real output is made and only headers are set, is just unnecessary. / As for the problem, have you tried and opened one of those corrupt, >2GB files in a text or hex editor to check and see if they perhaps contain any error messages (from either PHP or the command line tar call)?

Comment: I tried that and there are no error messages

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have issue with the headers 
try these

```
header("Content-Type: application/x-gzip-compressed");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
```

Try This

```
function downloadTar($filename, $path)
{
    $path_file = $path."/".$filename ;
    if(file_exists($path_file))
    {
        header("Content-Type: application/x-gzip-compressed");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile("$path_file"); 
        exit;
    }   

}
```